# Additional width for first element of Column in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-column

I am trying to achieve two evenly spaced buttons within a Column in Flutter. on Repeating the widgets twice, the first button is Shrunk by a specific width. On inspection, found this.[image: inspection image]

I'm unable to identify the cause for this unknown width. Here is the code for reference.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Text('Findo', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => {print('pressed')},
                    child: Text(
                      'Store Login',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                            100, 20, 100, 20),
                        primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)))),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => {print('pressed')},
                    child: Text(
                      'Customer Login',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                            100, 20, 100, 20),
                        primary: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)))),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ElevatedButton` has no height or width constraint. It takes space or (width and height) in respect of inside content. In your case `Store` and `Customer` is not same length. So customer button has more width than Store. You can wrap the button with a container and give them a width like this-

```
             Container(
                      width: 300,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => {print('pressed')},
                      child: Text(
                      'Store Login',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                  ),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                100, 20, 100, 20),
                primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius:
                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)))),
                ),
                    ),
```